# What are the odds two permutations in S_n do NOT generate the whole group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, co.combinatorics

**What are the odds two uniformly chosen elements of S_n span the whole group (or just the alternating group)?**  Mathematica experements suggest those odds approach 1 - this might have been proven a long time ago.  How likely is it to get the alternating group or something much smaller?

Also, **how can you *efficiently* find the size of the subgroup $\langle a,b\rangle$ in S_n ?**  My crude tests consists of randomly multiplying the two permutations and seeing how many different elements you get.  Maybe there's a more efficient way to generate all the elements spanned by two permutation.

---

You *can* generate the whole permutation group using a swap (12) and a shift (12...n).  I wonder if all two element generating sets are conjugate to this.

Comment: The odds can't approach 1; with probability 1/4, both permutations are alternating. You might want to check your code for bugs.

Comment: So the first order is the parity and second order is whether they fix a common element.  Maybe there is a representation-theoretic way to unify these two kinds of obstructions.  Certainly if they both fix the same $m$ elements, the subgroup will be smaller.  The higher order "cousins" of parity are less obvious.

Comment: John, there is nothing "representation-theoretic" about it - this is an elementary group theory.  Read Ph. Hall's http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/os-7/1/134.extract to see how does this work, as well as Shalev's survey I mentioned below.  Also, while I am at it, "all two element generating sets are conjugate to this" is the opposite of the truth, since conjugates of a transposition is a transposition.  Finally, to see the size of the permutation subgroup use the Schreier–Sims algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%E2%80%93Sims_algorithm

Comment: I mean... what characterizes pairs of permutations that generate all of $S_n$ (or if they're both even $A_n$)?  Also Sage Online already has a way to find orders of perm groups (probably using this Schrier-Sims algorithm with GAP).  Maybe a good book on permutation groups has a description.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The probability of generation of $A_n$ or $S_n$ by two random permutations is $1 - 1/n - O(1/n^2)$.  The $1/n$ term comes from both permutations having the same fixed point.  This is a classical result of L. Babai:  The probability of generating the symmetric group, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A, 1989.  Warning: it uses the classification of finite simple groups.

For asymptotics for general simple groups, see [this paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/r32065tp23lu7847/) by Liebeck and Shalev, and a recent [short survey](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/DMJDMV/xvol-icm/02/Shalev.MAN.ps.gz) by Shalev.

Comment: What's classical about 1989!?

Comment: A nonrigorous explanation for that asymptotic is easy: Two elements fail to generate the whole symmetric group if they are in some maximal subgroup. Both are in a subgroup of index $k$ with probability $1/k^2$ and the small index maximal subgroups of $S_n$ are $A_n$ and $n$ copies of $S_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Henry:  sometimes papers become classical rather quickly.  See http://bit.ly/d8Nub7 which finds a "classical 1998 paper" reference in a 2004 paper!  

Comment: Igor - huh, nice!  So it's not just mathematicians that confuse 'classical' with 'classic'.

Comment: The way I've heard it, "classical" means "it was known when I was in grad school".

Comment: @Henry: "classical" means "before the arXiv".

Comment: I interpret "classical" as "from a time when a significant portion of the mathematical technology used today in this subject was unavailable".  

Comment: Terry, by your definition all very old papers (including really bad ones) are classical.  My view is more restrictive: these are papers which significantly advanced these technologies you mentioned.  

Comment: For me, the word 'classical' (as distinct from 'classic' - they are used interchangeably, but have completely different connotations) connotes a 'classical period', and it's absurd to invoke the 'classical period' of each minor mathematical subfield.  Anyway, this is in danger of turning into a discussion, so I'll get off my hobby horse.  But not before noting that I think the theorem of Jordan that I quote in my answer *can* reasonably be called 'classical'.

Comment: The link to Liebeck and Shalev's paper at `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine. The link to Shalev's survey is also not working for me, but it seems to be available from https://www.emis.de/journals/DMJDMV/xvol-icm/02/Shalev.MAN.html. The `bit.ly` link in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45505/what-are-the-odds-two-permutations-in-s-n-do-not-generate-the-whole-group/45509#comment109164_45509) above now takes me to a search on Google for "clssical Tao theorem", which returns zero results.

Answer (score 15):

See John D Dixon, The probability of generating the symmetric group, Math Z 110 (1969) 199-205. Theorem 1. The proportion of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, $x$ and $y$ in $S_n$, which generate either $A_n$ or $S_n$ is greater than $1-2/(\log\log n)^2$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Whether you get $A_n$ or $S_n$ is just a question of whether both permutations are even, so the chances of spanning the whole group approach 3/4.

Answer (score 7):

Concerning the second part of the OP's question:

> Also, how can you efficiently find the size of the subgroup $\langle a,b \rangle$ in
>   $S_n$ ? My crude tests consists of randomly multiplying the two permutations and seeing
>   how many different elements you get. Maybe there's a more efficient way to generate all
>   the elements spanned by two permutation.

There is a "classical" polynomial-time method known as the "Schreier-Sims" algorithm for finding the order of the subgroup of $S_n$ generated by a given set of permutations - just google it for further details. It has a number of improvements for dealing with groups of very large degree. Refinements of this were used by Sims to prove the existence of some of the large sporadic finite simple groups, including the Lyons group and the Baby Monster.

There are also very fast "one-sided Monte-Carlo" probabilistic algorithms for verifying that the group generated by a given set of permutations is $A_n$ or $S_n$. If they do, then "yes" will be returned rapidly with high probability. If they do not, then the algorithm does not terminate, so normally you would give up and use Schreier-Sims instead. This method is based on old results due to Jordan and others, which say that if $G \le S_n$ is transitive and contains an element of prime order $p$ with $n/2 < p < n-2$, then  $G = A_n$ or $S_n$.

For further details, see Akos Seress' book "Permutation Group Algorithms" Cambridge University Press, 2003, or my own book, with B. Eick and E.A. O'Brien,  "Handbook of Computational Group Theory", CRC Press, 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the last part of your question: no, there are other two-element generating sets.  I don't have an explicit example to hand, though they should be easy enough to write down, but their existence can be deduced from the following theorem of Jordan.

**Theorem (Jordan, 1871):** There is a function $J :\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with the following properties:

1. $J(n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$;
2. if $\Gamma\to S_n$ is primitive with minimal degree at most $J(n)$ then the image
   of $\Gamma$ is the symmetric group $S_n$ or the alternating group $A_n$.

In particular, this means that a large cycle $(1,\ldots, p)$ for $p$ prime and another cycle $(1,\ldots,2n)$ for $2n\leq J(p)$ will together generate $S_p$.

Comment: On reflection, I suppose that also follows from the result of Dixon.  Still, this is another way to think about it.

Comment: Is 1. necessary to state?  Aren't all functions $J :\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $J(n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Ross - er, no.  Eg $J(n)=2$ (which also satisfies part 2).

Comment: Perhaps this is the point of confusion: 'function' in this context just means 'set map'.